# поиск и удаление нескольких строк, включая пустую

Tags: sed

Есть файл содержащий строки:

```
text
text
time

time

time

time

time
```

Нужно найти и удалить строки с time и следующую пустую, чтобы получилось

```
text
text
```

`sed '/time/{N;/\^\$/s/.*/d/}' file` не получилось

`sed '/time/{N;//s/.*//}' file` удаляются строки с time, пустые остаются

Comment: `sed '/time/{N;d}' file`

Comment: но чтобы удалять именно пару строк — «`time`, затем пустая», а не «`time`, затем любая строка»: `sed '/^time$/{N;/^time\n$/d}' file`

Comment: Для примера выше, работает. Но в случае `echo -e "text\ntext\ntime\ntime\n\ntime\n\ntime\n\ntime\n\ntime\n\ntime\n\ntext" | sed '/^time$/{N;/^time\n$/d}'` выводит строку `time` и следующую пустую. При этом строку  `time`, где следом идет непустая выводит правильно

Comment: *удалить строки с time и следующую пустую, чтобы получилось* — противоречит тому, что приведено: куда делась последняя строка, содержащая `time`? после неё ведь нет пустой строки.

Comment: Когда писал вопрос не заметил, что последняя пустая строка не выделяется при форматировании, поэтому добавил скрипт. Не понятно, почему sed по этому шаблону оставляет пустую строку

Comment: Я таки дико изиняюсь, но судя по приведенному желаемому результату, там пустых строк вообще оставаться не должно. Если это так, то не вижу повода не сделать так `sed -E ‘/(^time|^$)/d’`

Comment: Нужно было мне изначально приложить скрипт `echo -e "text\ntext\ntime\ntime\n\ntime\n\ntime\n\ntime\n\ntime\n\ntime\n\ntext"`. Суть задачи удалить строку с time и следующую пустую, а не выйти на результат в примере. В наборе строк может быть какое-угодно сочетание time, text и \n. В принципе вариант `sed '/^time$/{N;/^time\n$/d}'` и еще один sed по пустой строке решит поставленную задачу